# Custom Json.Net converter with List<Dynamic>

Tags: asp.net-core, json.net

In my ASP.Net Core API project I have a class I am deserializing with a custom converter on a List of Dynamic values:

```
    [JsonConverter(typeof(AddYearJsonConverter ))]
    public List<dynamic> Value { get; set; }
```

How, in my converter, do I see if the dynamic object is a DateTimeOffset, then if so, add a Year to the value before deserializing?

```
public class AddYearJsonConverter : JsonConverter<DateTimeOffset?>
{
    public override DateTimeOffset? ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, DateTimeOffset? existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // ?? How to check type and add a year??
        JObject obj = JObject.Load(reader);
        return serializer.Deserialize<DateTimeOffset?>(reader);
    }
```

Comment: There is no predefined JSON primitive for date/time, see [Serializing Dates in JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DatesInJSON.htm).  Json.NET has some heuristics to try to recognize date/time strings and parse them as `DateTime` or `DateTimeOffset` as specified by the [`DateParseHandling`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_DateParseHandling.htm) enumeration.

Comment: So basically there's not enough information in your post to determine whether you can do this reliably.  E.g. Might your dynamic data have contained both `DateTime` and `DateTimeOffset` objects when serializing?  Or might it contain string values that happen to look like datetime values?

Comment: Can you provide the current json format for our reference? Do you only need to make changes when json is converted to object or what changes are needed when object is converted to json (just WriteJson), hope you can provide more information.

Comment: Hi Yongqing The Json is unknown , the data is a List of Dynamic. The issues is that we want to loop thorugh the data and when a date is found, edit it. Because JsonReader is forward only, we can't look into it to see the data, then pass it to the Deserializer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are adding a custom `AddYearJsonConverter` to the **Value** field, you should return **the same type of Value** in the `ReadJson` method of AddYearJsonConverter.

Then load reader through `JToken`, by looping through each field value in the token, it is forcibly converted to the `DateTimeOffset` type. If successful, the corresponding date is added by one year, otherwise no change needed to made.

Here is the code:

```
   public class AddYearJsonConverter : JsonConverter<List<dynamic>>
    {
        public override List<dynamic> ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, List<dynamic> existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);
            List<dynamic> data = new List<dynamic>();
            foreach (var Value in token)
            {
                try
                {
                    DateTimeOffset dto = DateTimeOffset.Parse(Value.ToString()).AddYears(1);
                    data.Add(dto);
                }
                catch
                {
                    data.Add(Value);
                }

            }
            return data;
        }
        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, List<dynamic> value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
        }

    }
```